# Why would a dinosaur be there when chrome is offline

Tags: browser, chrome

I was wondering why google chrome's team replaced the sad face with a dinosaur on the browser when we are not connected to the internet. (not many dinosaurs use the internet, I hope). Is the dinosaur lost too?

[image]

And why did they remove the famous Star Trek line "He's dead, Jim!" .

Comment: I am not sure how this is an UX question...

Comment: No internet, what are you like in the age of the dinosaurs or summink innit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could think of two reasons

- a link to Mozilla, which wouldn't make much sense, if you ask me
- you're offline, you dinosaur!

Comment: I believe this is exactly it.

Comment: Yeap for the second point!! Who's offline these days!? :D

Comment: http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/chromes-offline-dinosaur.html Yup